# ドラクエのようなドット絵画像のバイナリ内から色情報を取得したい

Tags: unity3d, 画像, バイナリファイル

#### 目的

ドラクエのようなRPGをUnityで作りたいと思っている。
その過程でフィールドのマップチップが欲しいがフリー素材を良いものが無いので
BMPファイルをバイナリエディタで開きドット絵メーカー等に色の並びを落とし込んで１つ１つのマップチップを自作したい

#### やった事

フリー素材でフィールドのマップチップになるようなものをひたすら検索
[こちら](http://infoseek_rip.g.ribbon.to/xb_lim.at.infoseek.co.jp/dq/1zentai.png)のサイトからドラクエ１の世界地図をUnity内に取り込んでSpriteEditorで分割してみたが一つ一つの画質がとても粗い

#### やりたい事の詳細・質問

BMPファイルはヘッダー位置が決まっているので、バイナリエディタで開くと色の配合を取得できるのではと考えていて、その色の配合を[ドット絵メーカー](https://neutralx0.net/tools/dot3/)に投げれば１つ１つの地形画像を取得でき、それを出力すれば１つ１つのマップチップが作成できると思うんですが色情報の取り方がわかっていません。
色情報を取る方法やドット素材を作るのに便利な方があれば教えてください。

#### 開発環境

Unity 2023.2.8f1

#### 言語

C#

#### 追記（言葉足らずな部分があるので）

私自身は絵を描く能力はありません、
エンジニアリング（ツール操作等も含む）による解決方法を模索しております。

Comment: ファミコンの画面解像度は 256x224 とかなので、その上のほんの一部である部品はもっと画像が小さい＝現代PCで見ると「とても粗い」のは当たり前なのではないか、と。そもそも DQ の絵は自由に使っていいの？　bmp ファイルのフォーマットは検索すればいくらでも出てきますが、検索しました？

Comment: ＞そもそも DQ の絵は自由に使っていいの？
もちろんそのものを使ったら著作権があるのでダメですよ、それに似せたドット打ちを行ってフィールドを作ってみるのは、マップチップを作る手掛かりになると思いますがいかがですか？

Comment: ＞bmp ファイルのフォーマットは検索すればいくらでも出てきますが、検索しました？
致しました。ヘッダー位置となるヘキサもわかったので、後は画像に対して該当する部分のヘキサを抜き出せればと思っています。　その方法を調べているところです。手法を知りたいんです。

Comment: どこかから色を取ってくる必要性とは…？（自分で絵を描くならば，単に見た目に似た色を用意して使えばそれで良いのでは？　何かに「似たような絵」を描くとき，「似たような色」を使うのではダメな理由とは何か？）

Comment: ＞どこかから色を取ってくる必要性とは…？：自分で絵が描けないので、画像が持ってる内部情報からドット絵を再現がしたいという事です。

Comment: ＞何かに「似たような絵」を描くとき，「似たような色」を使うのではダメな理由とは何か？）：似たような色の16進数の組み合わせがわからないと再現できないからです。絵が描けない以上はどういうピクセルの組み合わせで例えば平地１つは表現するのかを知る必要があります。

Comment: どんな手段で作業する想定なのかわかりませんが，大抵の絵を作るソフトってGUI上で色を選択できませんかね．そういうので「このへんかなー」っていう色を選べば済む話じゃないんですか？　「手本とする絵を目視して，それに近い色を見た目で選ぶ」だと不都合な理由がわかりませんし，仮に完全一致した色じゃないと嫌だとかいう場合でも目視に用いている手段で色情報くらい見れるのでは（回答でも言われているけどスポイト機能とかで）

Answer (score 1):

なんだか限りなく XY 問題というか。あなたの最終目標は絵を描くことであって bmp ファイルを分析することではないはず。手段が目的と化していませんか？

絵が描きたいのならドット絵メーカーにこだわる必然はないので、他のツールを使っても良いわけです。例えば Windows 10 だったら [ペイント3D] が付属しています。このソフト、名前に反して 2D 画像も作れます。 bmp ファイルを開くことができます。拡大縮小表示もできます。色の抽出機能もあります。アイコン１枚描くだけならこれでも十分実用になります。 Visual Studio Community にもアイコンエディタ機能が内蔵されています。もちろん Illustrator とか Inkscape とか GIMP とか使ってもいいです。

それでも bmp ファイルの分析ソフトが作りたいというなら、少なくとも作成する言語であるとか処理系であるとかは公開してください。でないとアドバイスのしようがないです。 bmp は長い歴史の中で拡張が繰り返されてきたフォーマットなので、これを真面目に分析しようとするとものすごく面倒そう。分析ソフトを自作ることはお勧めしないっス。分析ソフト作る時間で何十枚も絵が描けそう。

Comment: どちらかというとそもそも絵が描けないので、フリーで公開されているBMP画像から所定の位置を抜き出してそれをドット打ちで再現できれば度の地形やキャラもつくれるよね？という考えです。まずは平地と言う1キャラ乗るぐらいのドット画像16進数の構成知りたいのですが、バイナリエディタを使ってもたどり着けていないという感じです。　バイナリエディタとしてはBzエディタとStirlingを試してみました。

Comment: ペイント3Dは使ったことが無いのでこちらは調べてみて使い方を試してみます。

Comment: ＞bmp ファイルの分析ソフトが作りたいというなら：分析したいだけで作りたくはないです。こちらのRFC7854（https://tex2e.github.io/rfc-translater/html/rfc7854.html?fbclid=IwAR0vINJq_vvnxVgt3u1lRK1Ph2gQ6I9uk75KtfCFU-wD0qq2X9KlqorZLsY）に沿った仕組みを作れる気がしないので

Answer (score 1):

@774RR さんも指摘していますが、バイナリエディタでBMPをパースするのは茨の道かと…

[BMPの仕様](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_bitmap) を読むとわかりますが、1ピクセルの色情報を得るまでが結構手間ですし、そもそも入力画像のカラーフォーマットと、OPさんの期待する色配合のカラーフォーマットが異なる場合、カラーフォーマット変換も必要になります（e.g. `r3g3b2` -> `r8g8b8a8`）。

ですので、以下のアプローチを提案します。

1. 比較的高機能なペインターである GIMP や Photoshop のスポイトや矩形選択ツールなどを駆使する。
2. C++に知見があるならば、例えば [OpenCV](https://github.com/opencv/opencv) で画像の色情報と切り抜きをプログラム的に取り扱う。
3. シェルスクリプトに知見があるならば、ImageMagickのコマンドラインツールで色情報を得たり、画像切り出しを行う。
   英: [ImageMagick get pixel color by x y coordinates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69697173/imagemagick-get-pixel-color-by-x-y-coordinates)
4. [XPM](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPM) のような、より簡素な画像フォーマットで歩みを進める。

Comment: ＞比較的高機能なペインターである GIMP や Photoshop のスポイトや矩形選択ツールなどを駆使する。：絵の上手さが求められてないのであれば試してみます。

Comment: ＞C++に知見があるならば、例えば OpenCV で画像の色情報と切り抜きをプログラム的に取り扱う。：こちらは使い方を調べてみます。

Comment: ＞シェルスクリプトに知見があるならば、ImageMagickのコマンドラインツールで色情報を得たり、画像切り出しを行う。：こちらも頑張ればできるかもしれないので調べてみます。

Comment: ＞XPM のような、より簡素な画像フォーマットで歩みを進める。：まずはXPMのお勉強からとUnity内にインポートした時に画像を認識できるかになりそうです。

Answer (score 0):

いまいち何を求めているのかが把握できていない感じですが，

> ドラクエ１

とか

> ドット絵

とかいう言葉から察するに，パレットを使う（フルカラーとかじゃない）タイプのBMPを相手にするので十分だろうと思うので，何かしらパレット情報を表示したり扱うことができるソフトを探してくるのが手っ取り早いのではないでしょうか．

↓の画像は IrfanView での例ですが，こんなのが見れれば良いのでは？
（IrfanView ならパレットの内容をテキストな感じにエクスポートもできる様子）

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: この質問のタイトル「色情報を取得」はこれが一番簡単そう。ただ色だけあっても絵にはならないという意味では質問者氏の最終目的を達することにはならないかもしれないっスね。

Comment: 著作権に関して 「それに似せたドット打ちを行って…」 と述べられていますし，なんだかんだ言っても絵は自前で描く必要があると思うのですが，そこに関してどういう作業を想定されているのかがわかりませんので，何とも…（そもそも色を取得する意味自体もわからないのですが）